# SELECT Query with LIKE '%b-%' returns 0 row on MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-like

In my sql query, I execute code with `'%b-%'` and query returns 0 row.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME, AGE FROM PERSONS WHERE NAME LIKE '%b-%'
```

and without like :

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME, AGE FROM PERSONS WHERE NAME = 'b-rush'
```

All queries returns 0 row.

I have values like `'b-rush'`, `'b-rush1'`, `'b-rush2'`, etc.

Comment: Show some sample data

Comment: What is the collation of the db you're querying? Is it case-sensitive by chance (unusual but happens).

Comment: Silly question, but since you're using MS SQL Server, are you sure you selected the right database?

Comment: Kill the where clause altogether ; do you get results?

Comment: Did you get any result when you excute `SELECT NAME, SURNAME, AGE FROM PERSONS`?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I think, sample data is enough to understand problem .)

Comment: - abatishchev Collation : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CI_AS. It is not case-sensitive. If value is 'b' and i use 'b', is it important to be or not to be case-sensitive?

- DHLopez Yes, I am sure that I am using the right database.

- EatPeanutButter I have tried without where. Of course i get results. It's most used table on db. Users addd about 4k-5k rows everyday.

- Sami Sure, i got.

Thank for all your replies but i am not a newbie .)

Comment: @Xaithe can you select all rows, find a row with `b-rush`, copy that value and try with `where =` ? it might be that there are some invisible characters

Comment: Could it be a case of the dash vs the hyphen? try copying a value and using it in the where condition to see if it returns results rather than typing in the value.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I have tried that but but result was the same.
-Sam I have tried..

Comment: What if you do `like '%b%'` ? Can you post your table schema and some data?

Comment: You might benefit from experimenting with `SELECT NAME, SURNAME, AGE, case when Name like '%b-%' then 1 else 0 end as Matched FROM PERSONS` and changing the condition within the `case` expression.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @abatishchev, The table can have difference of collation, if the collation is

- CI = Case-insensitive, your query will work ok
- CS = Case-sensitive, you need use correct case in the query

  ```
  DECLARE @PERSONS table (NAME_CASE_Insensitive   varchar(30) COLLATE 
  Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS NOT NULL 
                          ,NAME_CASE_sensitive  varchar(30) COLLATE 
  Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS NOT NULL 
                          )
  insert @PERSONS (NAME_CASE_Insensitive , NAME_CASE_sensitive) values 
  ('B-rush','B-rush'),('b-rush1','B-rush1'),('b-rush2','B-rush2')
  ```

Case Insensitive - Returns all

```
SELECT * FROM @PERSONS WHERE NAME_CASE_Insensitive = 'b-rush'


NAME_CASE_Insensitive          NAME_CASE_sensitive
------------------------------ ------------------------------
B-rush                         B-rush
```

---

Case Sensitive - Returns nothing

```
SELECT * FROM @PERSONS WHERE NAME_CASE_sensitive = 'b-rush'
NAME_CASE_Insensitive          NAME_CASE_sensitive
------------------------------ ------------------------------
```

---

Case Insensitive - Returns all

```
SELECT* FROM @PERSONS WHERE NAME_CASE_Insensitive LIKE '%b-%'

    NAME_CASE_Insensitive          NAME_CASE_sensitive
    ------------------------------ ------------------------------
    B-rush                         B-rush
    b-rush1                        B-rush1
    b-rush2                        B-rush2
```

---

Case Sensitive - Returns nothing

```
SELECT* FROM @PERSONS WHERE NAME_CASE_sensitive LIKE '%b-%'
NAME_CASE_Insensitive          NAME_CASE_sensitive
------------------------------ ------------------------------
```

---

Case Sensitive - Returns all

```
SELECT* FROM @PERSONS WHERE NAME_CASE_sensitive LIKE '%B-%'
NAME_CASE_Insensitive          NAME_CASE_sensitive
------------------------------ ------------------------------
B-rush                         B-rush
b-rush1                        B-rush1
b-rush2                        B-rush2
```

---

Correct like to case sensitive

```
SELECT* FROM @PERSONS WHERE NAME_CASE_sensitive LIKE '%[bB]-%'
NAME_CASE_Insensitive          NAME_CASE_sensitive
------------------------------ ------------------------------
B-rush                         B-rush
b-rush1                        B-rush1
b-rush2                        B-rush2
```

Comment: as i said, my table is Case-insensitive.

Answer (score -2):

Change the currently selected database.

[Correct Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDJHF.jpg)
[Wrong database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnC2y.jpg)

This is something that can happen if the creation of the tables was messy.

Say you run a new query on SQL Management Studio:

```
CREATE TABLE test (temp nvarchar(7))
```

And you have Master selected in the dropdown you see in my screenshots. You *have* created a Test table, but on Master. Generally, you don't want this, so you create it on a specific database instead by either specifying it on the query or modifying the selected dropdown option.

```
CREATE TABLE MyDatabase.dbo.test (temp nvarchar(7))
```

You now have the tables on BOTH Master and MyDatabase. If you ran your select query, that does not specify the DB name, it would use whatever is selected in that dropdown. Which could be Master, which likelly is not the one with your data.

Comment: Come on, it has nothing to do with the OP question, If it had, the OP would get an error. The OP stated he is getting 0 results.

Comment: That depends on how he did the inserts. If, for some reason, MASTER has the tables (which is not too impossible if the CREATE TABLE queries ran against Master), the query _will_ return no results, for apparently no reason. Admittedly, I should've been more clear.

Comment: Even he create the table in another db, that will return error message "couldn't find table name, not 0 rows

Comment: Not if the table exists on both databases. The answer as to whether this is a collation issue or the issue i stated really comes down to "does SELECT NAME, SURNAME, AGE FROM PERSONS return anything?"

Comment: As i said. I am not a newbie .)